# Replace string after some char

Tags: python, string

How can I replace substring from string? For example I have strings:

```
string1/aaa
this is string2/bbb
string 3/ccc
this is some string/ddd
```

And I want to read substring after "/". I need this output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can split the string to get the data

```
my_string.split("/")[1]
```

For example,

```
data = ["string1/aaa", "this is string2/bbb", "string 3/ccc",
        "this is some string/ddd"]    
print [item.split("/")[1] for item in data]
```

**Output**

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using re:

```
>>> data = """string1/aaa
... this is string2/bbb
... string 3/ccc
... this is some string/ddd"""
>>>
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.*?\/(\w+)', data)
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
>>>
```

Comment: Let's note that when splitting at a constant string split() is sufficient and you don't need the machinery of regular expressions which causes some extra overhead.

Comment: Yes i do understand, I was just showing a way of doing it, he was not asking for the most efficient one. Any way thanks for your advice.

Comment: Of course! I just felt it would be useful to add a footnote to your answer.